# HttpContext.Current.Session is NULL in Mozilla

Tags: session, cross-browser, handler, mozilla

While accessing session data in c# class in Mozilla, it is returning NULL :(
I have added IRequiresSessionState to handler.

It is working fine in other BROWSER.
 Reference link

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1137385&start=0

http://forums.asp.net/t/1585703.aspx?Need+to+access+session+variables+in+an+ashx+

Thanks